# SQL Server : how can I find the specific value from all stored procedures in my database?

Tags: sql-server, database

How can I find the specific value from all stored procedures in my SQL Server database?

To be more specific, I want to know the value that is inserted into the specified column on the specified table.

For example:

- A database has 3 stored procedures; `dbo.sp_1`, `dbo.sp_2`, `dbo.sp_3`
- And that database also has a `[Log]` table which has a `[number]` column

**dbo.sp_1**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Log] ([number]) 
VALUES (1);
```

**dbo.sp_2**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Log] ([number]) 
VALUES (2);
```

**dbo.sp_3**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Log] ([number]) 
VALUES (4);
```

So, the query results I expect are as follows:

[image]

Comment: Afraid there's no good way to query this.  You'd have to parse the actual procedure code to find it programatically.  If you need to know the source that writes a value to a row in a table you'd be better off adding a `SP` column to `dbo.Log` and writing a string literal as the column value during your `INSERT`.  Then it's just a simple query of the table.

Comment: @squillman Thank you for the comment, but I have another columns like that. That's just an example.

Comment: Well, it's not going to change the fact that you'll have to programatically parse the stored procedure code to find the values you're looking for, which SQL Server is terrible at.

Comment: If you know you need to do this ahead of time then adding a formatted comment to the procedure text that you can search for, extract and parse would save you a lot of time, although this does sound like an XY problem, I've never needed anything like this in 25 years..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a snippet that was used for a somewhat-similar task, however, I did not have to parse values. This may get you close if you really have to parse the sql. Sorry, the rest of the parsing will be left up to you

```
DECLARE @NonEscapeTextToFindLike NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERTINTO\[dbo\].\[LOG\](\[number\])VALUES('
DECLARE @NonEscapeTextToFind NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERTINTO[dbo].[LOG]([number])VALUES('

;WITH Procs AS
(
    SELECT 
        StoredProcedure = name,
        StoredProcedureText = OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id),
        NoBlankText = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id),' ',''),CHAR(9),''),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')
    FROM   
        sys.procedures
)

SELECT
    *,
    StartOfPossibleInt = CHARINDEX(@NonEscapeTextToFind, Procs.NoBlankText) + LEN(@NonEscapeTextToFind)
FROM
    Procs
WHERE
    Procs.NoBlankText LIKE '%'+@NonEscapeTextToFindLike+'%' ESCAPE '\'
```